# C++ char array addition

Tags: c++

So I recently started learning C++, been watching a lot of tutorials and stumbled upon a tricky question. I want to enter a max number n and enter two numbers stored in a char array. Then I would want to pass them into my add function to do simple addition. It would always return a letter though. I know it has to do with the char ASCII, but is there any way besides using strings to accomplish this?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void add(char m1[], char m2[], int n);

int main()
{
int n = 0;
cin >> n;

const char CAPACITY = 100;
char m1[CAPACITY] = {0};
char m2[CAPACITY] = {0};

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cin >> m1[i];

}
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cin >> m2[i];

}
add(m1, m2, n);


}

void add(char m1[], char m2[], int n)
{
char sum[100] = {0};
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    sum[i] = m1[i] + m2[i];
}

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cout << sum[i];
}
```

Comment: why do you use `char`? And what do you expect the sum to mean? What should `'a' + 'b'` be? What should `'z' + 'e'` be? What should `'a' + 'A'` be?

Comment: also, as a side note, but very important, you are not learning C++. You are learning C disguised as C++. That's not what C++ should look like. In C++ you use standard containers like `std::string` and `std::vector`.

Comment: @bolov you don't use an `std::vector` to store a sequence of characters. That's called an `std::string`. Thanks for your comment though, cause the above code is not c++

Comment: Was just trying to see how char array works. So for example if I enter 4 as max amount of elements n, then for example, enter 3000 for m1, and 1000 for m2. Would like to find the sum of these two separate arrays.

Comment: @Jason please get a good book for the language!

Comment: "but is there any way besides using strings to accomplish this?" Accomplish what?

Answer (score 1):

It's important to know the difference between `'3'` and `3`. The first is a character, a  symbol. The second is a number formed of one digit. In C++ unfortunately and confusing for beginners characters can sometimes appear to act as numbers. They are implicitly convertible to integers and operations like summing them are allowed, although it doesn't make any sense to add two symbols. When a character is *acting up* as a number its numeric value is the character representation code. I.e. each character has a code (or number) associated with it as part of the character encoding scheme. The most used character encoding scheme for `char` is ASCII.

When you do `'3' + '0'` you are actually adding the character codes. If you look in an ASCII table you will see that the code for `'3'` is `51` and the code for `'0'` is `48` so the result is `99`. Due to the implicit (hidden) conversions happening in `'3' + '0'` the result (`99`) is of type `int`, not `char`.

More formally, `'3' + '0'` is equivalent to:

```
static_cast<int>('3') + static_cast<int>('0')
```

When you store the result (remembers the result it's an `int`) to a `char` (like you do in `sum[i] = m1[i] + m2[i]` then the integer is implicitly converted to a char. Again, if you look in the ASCII table you see that the code `99` corresponds to the character `'e'`.

It helps a lot if you think of characters as symbols. There are alpha characters: `'a'`, `'b'`, etc.; digit characters: `'0'`, `'1'`, etc.; punctuation and whitespace characters: `' '`, `';'`, `'-'` etc. and control characters: `'\0'` etc. It helps a lot if you think of all of them being in the same boat. It helps if you think as `'a'` and `'3'` being both symbols, being of same type. Then you will see that `'3' + '0'` doesn't make sense any more than `'a' + 'b'` makes sense.

> I, but is there any way besides using strings to accomplish this?

You mean to add two numbers? Sure:

```
int a, b;
std::cin >> a >> b;
int sum = a + b;
std::cout << sum << std::endl;
```

Mind. Blown.